# COALESCE and NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

I want to create an SQL query (using Oracle) where I am combining the values across 2 columns, each of which exist in different tables (they are joined by a CODE). Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.SERIES1,b.SERIES2)
FROM TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b
WHERE a.CODE = b.CODE
```

However, when I join columns together, I also want to return null as well. I think I am only getting the instances where SERIES1 = SERIES2...

Ideally, I want to get the following:

- If SERIES1 is not null, return SERIES1
- If SERIES2 is not null, return SERIES2
- If SERIES1 and SERIES2 are both null, return null

I hope I am making this clear and that I'm using the correct terminology...

Thanks!

Comment: `COALESCE(a.SERIES1,b.SERIES2)` should return null if both columns are null. What does it return?

Comment: The COALESCE function returns the first non-null expression in the list. If all expressions evaluate to null, then the COALESCE function will return null. Look at your JOIN.

Comment: It seems like you want to return `SERIES1` as well as `SERIES2` if both of these values are not `NULL`? Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not with the `COALESCE`, but rather with the way that you did a join. It appears that you may be looking for an *outer join*, while you did an *inner join*.

Although Oracle has its own syntax for doing an outer join the way you did (i.e. by listing two tables and placing the join condition in the `WHERE` clause) the ANSI syntax should be preferred:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.SERIES1,b.SERIES2)
FROM TABLE1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.CODE = b.CODE
```